# Access reports, exporting to Word

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created a Microsoft Access Report, with a number of elements in them.  These include labels, controls, lines, boxes, etc.  When I export the report to Word, it loses all lines, borders, boxes, etc.  Is there a way to keep this in an export?  Exporting to PDF is fine, but I need this to work in a Word export.

thanks

Comment: VTC - More suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Hello.  I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: Jason - this question is more suited for SuperUser than StackOverflow, IMO.

Comment: Oh, OK.  I will add it there as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Might it work as a Word Mail Merge? However Mail merge will only work with a single data source. Depending on what your report actually consists of, it may not be feasible.

Comment: This has a number of tables and sub tables, which uses grouping.  Not sure that would work with a merge?

Comment: No, it wouldn't - Mail merge will only work with one data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you export a report to Word / RTF graphical elements like lines, ole objects, and attachment fields are not exported.  In order to preserve your line, you would need to export your report to a different format like PDF or XPS.